# Format Date with timezone (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following query which I'm unable to solve:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.id,
    TO_CHAR(m.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp AS formatted_date,
FROM table.match m
```

In the **formatted_date** field I get the following output:

> 2012-12-02T00:00:00.000Z

Does anyone know how to format it as to get just **2012-12-02**?

The version I'm using is: PostgreSQL 13.10

Thank you all for any help!

Comment: `to_char` returns formatted text, no need to cast it to `timestamp`. Just remove `::timestamp`.

Comment: Dates in all databases (except SQLite) are binary values, they have no format. What does `m.date` contain? What is its type? PostgreSQL and other databases use `date` for date-only values, and client languages can handle them just fine. You may not need to format anything

Comment: formatted_date is a _column_, not a field. And its values consist of a year field, a month field etc.

Comment: 1) What is the data type for `m.date`? 2) Do you want the output to be a `date` type or a `string`? If you want  a `date` then do `TO_CHAR(m.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date`. Otherwise leave off the cast.

Answer (score 0):

to get just 2012-12-02 :

```
SELECT 
   m.id,
   to_char(m.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as formatted_date
FROM table.match m
```

to remove time nut still have datetime datatype use date_trunc

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.id,
    date_trunc('day', m.date)::date AS formatted_date
FROM table.match m
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for the `2012-12-02` output, simply cast `m.date` to date type

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.id,
    m.date::DATE AS formatted_date
FROM table.match m;
```